# How to update a cell's content when its referenced cells content changes

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I looked through 'similar' questions but couldn't find a solution to my problem.  Basically I'm learning about events and notifiers and my problem is, how do I update a reference to a cell when the referenced cell's content changes.  For example: What I currently can do is reference another cells content.
If I have something like this

[image: Initial reference]

I get this

[image: Reference is good]

But if I update A1's cell to something else, how can I get C1 cell to update?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: problem]

Comment: [CellValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged). You can also work with the [EditingControlShowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged), for and *early* approach (managing the EditControl's Text value - this control is just a TextBox; you can also use your own control, replacing the default one). Many other ways. In any case, you need a map that links the cells with a formula to the cell(s) that provides the value(s).

Comment: For example, in the [CellValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=netframework-4.8) event, iterate through each cell of each row, detect the referenced cells, and update them accordingly.